# How to invoke MouseDoubleClick on Button code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I invoke MouseDoubleClick event on Button code behind?

I've tried something like this:

```
btn.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent));
```

but when I do so I receive the following error:

```
Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'.
```

Comment: Did you try passing `new MouseButtonEventArgs` instead of `RoutedEventArgs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [MouseButtonEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place of simple [RoutedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Code-behind:

```
private void button_WithDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Double click");
}

private void button_RaiseDoubleClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
    {
        RoutedEvent = Control.MouseDoubleClickEvent
    };

    this.button_WithDoubleClick.RaiseEvent(args);
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="button_WithDoubleClick" Content="Button with double click" MouseDoubleClick="button_WithDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="button_RaiseDoubleClick" Content="Button to raise double click" Click="button_RaiseDoubleClick_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**P.S.:** I am not sure what shall be given as the value of the second constructor param for the `MouseButtonEventArgs` - `The time when the input occurred.`. 0 works well in this demo, but whether it will work with more complex interactions I do not know.